# How do Zend 2 Validators work?

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2

I have a Form, and a User model. In the controller, I set the form validator to the `$user->getInputFilter()`. That works.

Then I add a captcha in the form, and without any other code, it seems to validate on its own. So I suspect each element can also have its own validator which will be called regardless of the form's "global" validator.

I'm building my form with ["Factory Backed Form extension"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#factory-backed-form-extension), and take [this code](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#form-elements) and add it like this (seems right, the password field does have `'name' => 'password'`):

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'password_confirm',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'required' => true,
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array('identical', false, array('token' => 'password'))
    )
));
```

But that doesn't validate (always passes). Looking at other code examples, it does seem fine to add input filters to individual elements; as mentioned above captcha seems self-validating but why not this? I know I could do my own check and use `$form->addError($message)` but I'm trying to learn Zend so I want to utilize as much of it as possible. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

create your custom validate password check.
answered here : http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Validation-identical-in-the-form-td671430.html